# Two always block in the same module. If the following technique is wrong someone suggest me an alternative way

Tags: verilog

I am using two always block in the same module. Will it cause an error to synthesizable code? The source code is written in Verilog given below

```
module Mux (input wire[7:0] iterate, input wire deterministicEnable, input wire bistMode, input wire enable, input wire clk, input wire rst, output reg[127:0] valueO);

    reg [9:0] seedVal[0:2];
    reg[31:0] generatePattern [0:3],temp;
    integer i;

    always begin
        @(deterministicEnable)begin
            if(deterministicEnable==1)begin
                temp<={22'b000000000000,seedVal[iterate]};
            end
        end
    end

    always@(posedge clk)begin
        if(rst)begin
            temp<=32'b11111111111111111111111111111111;
            seedVal[0]<=10'b1001100101;
            seedVal[1]<=10'b1111111111;
            seedVal[2]<=10'b0000011111;
            generatePattern[0]<=32'b00000000000000000000000000000000;
            generatePattern[1]<=32'b00000000000000000000000000000000;
            generatePattern[2]<=32'b00000000000000000000000000000000;
            generatePattern[3]<=32'b00000000000000000000000000000000;
        end
        else begin
            if((bistMode==1) && (enable==1))begin
                for(i=0;i<4;i=i+1)begin
                    temp = {(temp[31] ^ temp[25] ^ temp[22] ^ temp[21] ^ temp[15] ^ temp[11] ^ temp[10] ^ temp[9] ^ temp[7] ^ temp[6] ^ temp[4] ^ temp[3] ^ temp[1] ^ temp[0]), temp[31:1]};
                    generatePattern[i] = temp;
                end
                valueO = {generatePattern[3],generatePattern[2],generatePattern[1],generatePattern[0]};
            end
        end
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. As David suggested, this is not synthesizable because you drive `temp` from 2 different always blocks. To make it working, you need to combine both of them into a single one.
2. the first always is a complete mess which will behave as a messed-up flop in simulation due to truncated sensitivity list. Even if a synthesis tools would do something with the block, the result will not match simulation.
3. The second block might be synthesizable, but it will probably behave differently in hardware than in simuilation due to mixed use of blocking/non-blocking assignments for the same vars.

So, what to do.

1. you need to create a single always block out of 2 of them. It is difficult to see what your intent is, but in general it will probably look like:

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (rst) ...
    else if (deterministicEnable) ...
    else if if((bistMode==1) && (enable==1)) ..
end
```

2. it seems that both `temp` and `generatePattern` are internal variables and they do not need any reset. So, remove them from the `if (rst)` cluase. I do not see a need for `temp` at all in your code. You can remove it completely. There is also no use for the `seedVal`, so i do not see why you initialize them at all.
3. you are correct by using blocking assignments (=) for assigning to `temp` and to `generatePattern`, because they are internal vars. However `value0` is not internal and you should have used an nba (<=) to assign. For that reason the `value0` variable should be initialized with the `rst` signal, it is not.

Comment: Mr. Serge, I have used non-blocking assignment in the rst block and blocking assignment to the else block. How could they behave differently in hardware? I need a little bit more explanation.

Comment: in *always* blocks with posedge you should  always use *non-blocking* assignments for the outputs of the block, no matter if they are in rst or not. You should always use blocking assignment for internal vars, no matter where they are in the block. You should **never** mix blocking and non-blocking assignments to the same var. Internal vars should not be initialized within rst clause at all.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not synthesisable, an always block creates a driver for all the signals assigned in it and each signal must always have only one driver (ignoring some exceptions for tristate not relevant here).

```
always begin
    @(deterministicEnable)begin
```

is also not synthesisable as far as I know. If you want a combinational (not clocked), use `always @* begin`.

Comment: Mr. Shah (always begin  @(deterministicEnable)begin) I used only for initialization, beause i came to know that initial block is not synthesisabe. Can you please suggest me an alternative of that. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Initial blocks are synthesisable for (most) FPGAs. Alternatively you could use a power on reset signal add an `if (power_on_reset)` clause to the main always block where you set temp.

Comment: Should I use any time delay like #6 with the power_on_reset?

Comment: Time delays are not synthesisable, you would need to use something like a counter.

Comment: Would you please explain the use of counter a little bit more?